Previous uploaded Images gets vanished will inserting images in table Oracle
I have a stored procedure in which I am inserting or uploading some rows. While inserting, if the same row is inserted a second time, the earlier rows get deleted with other rows. I want to keep those rows while inserting the new one.
This is the query:
IF TBL_INSERT > 0 THEN
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_PANAROMICIMG_COUNT 
    FROM TBL_VSAT_IMAGE_DETAIL 
    WHERE IMG_TYPE = 'Panaromic' AND IMG_ID = TBL_INSERT;
       
    IF V_PANAROMICIMG_COUNT > 0 THEN
    BEGIN        
        DELETE FROM TBL_VSAT_IMAGE_DETAIL 
        WHERE IMG_TYPE = 'Panaromic' AND IMG_ID = TBL_INSERT;  
    END;        
END IF;  
       
IF P_PANORAMIC_IMAGES IS NOT NULL THEN
BEGIN
    FOR PMULTIFIELDS IN (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_PANORAMIC_IMAGES,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS IMAGES FROM DUAL
                                      CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_PANORAMIC_IMAGES, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
                                    )
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO TBL_VSAT_IMAGE_DETAIL (IMG_ID, IMG_NAME, IMG_TYPE, IMG_UPLOADED_DATE, UPLOADED_BY)
        VALUES (TBL_INSERT, PMULTIFIELDS.IMAGES, 'Panaromic', SYSDATE, P_CREATED_BY);
    END LOOP;
END;
       
END IF;

update


Table desc: TBL_VSAT_IMAGE_DETAIL

Name              Null?    Type            
----------------- -------- --------------- 
IMG_ID            NOT NULL NUMBER          
IMG_NAME                   NVARCHAR2(2000) 
IMG_TYPE                   NVARCHAR2(100)  
IMG_UPLOADED_DATE          DATE            
UPLOADED_BY                NVARCHAR2(100)  
ID                NOT NULL NUMBER  



Sample image name is 90.jpg, 120.jpg. So if the table consists image name with 90.jpg it for that ID then it should either update the image name or delete and insert the new image with same Image name

Without a reproducible test case, it's hard to guess.  You could remove the IF statement that causes rows to be deleted.  But we have no idea if that exists because of some other requirement that you haven't mentioned.

@JustinCave: Lets say I have Image as 1,2,3 then I save it and again upload 3,4,5 so what happens is 1,2,3 gets deleted.

Which, if we assume is being caused by the code in question, would be resolved by removing the IF statement that does the deletes.  But my guess is that statement wasn't added for fun, it was likely added for some other reason.  A reason that your test case should enumerate.

which IF, I have 2 if conditions ?

@JustinCave Suppose I removed second IF, then same images is inserted twice. that is why that second if is added in the query

@JustinCave: I don't want to insert the same image twice if possible if it gets updated then its OK

OK.  So then your reproducible test case would include sample data that tells us what you consider the "same image" and what you consider to be different images.  It is very hard to guess at what you really want that delete statement to delete if we don't know your table definition, we don't know what your data looks like, and we don't know what your requirements are.  Maybe you need another condition in the SELECT COUNT(*) statement or in the DELETE statement.

@JustinCave: I have added TABLE DESCRIPTION and logic which I m expecting. Please have a look

Your code is not syntactically valid and suffers from the same problem your previous questions have suffered from - you have unmatched BEGIN statements without a corresponding END statement. (And most of the times you use BEGIN and END they are redundant and could be removed.)

Use a MERGE statement to to either an INSERT or an UPDATE depending on whether the row already exists:
IF P_PANORAMIC_IMAGES IS NOT NULL THEN
  MERGE INTO TBL_VSAT_IMAGE_DETAIL dst
  USING (
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_PANORAMIC_IMAGES,'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS image_name
    FROM   DUAL
    CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_PANORAMIC_IMAGES, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
  ) src
  ON (   dst.img_id = TBL_INSERT
     AND dst.img_name = src.image_name )
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE
     SET img_type          = 'Panoramic',
         img_uploaded_date = SYSDATE,
         uploaded_by       = P_CREATED_BY
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (IMG_ID, IMG_NAME, IMG_TYPE, IMG_UPLOADED_DATE, UPLOADED_BY)
    VALUES (TBL_INSERT, src.image_name, 'Panaromic', SYSDATE, P_CREATED_BY);
END IF;

fiddle
Note: You probably do not want to DELETE beforehand so try removing the first IF statement - however your business logic is not fully explained so there may be a reason why you are doing that.
If you do need the DELETE (I don't think you do) then you do not need to check if rows exist before trying to delete them, just try to delete them and if there are no rows then nothing gets deleted. It can be simplified to:
IF TBL_INSERT > 0 THEN
  DELETE FROM TBL_VSAT_IMAGE_DETAIL 
  WHERE IMG_TYPE = 'Panaromic' AND IMG_ID = TBL_INSERT;  
END IF;  


Getting error as Error(967,28): PL/SQL: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword  at line INSERT INTO (IMG_ID, IMG_NAME, IMG_TYPE.....

Also, you have removed LOOP from your 1st query. is that not required ?

@hud Fixed and, no the loop is not necessary as the thing you are looping over is embedded into the MERGE statement. (And loops tend to be slow and inefficient.)

With merge, my all images are deleted with respect to that IMG_ID. it means update logic is not working

@hud Check the linked fiddle - the previous images are not deleted.

I guess before our procedure i m adding this line IF V_PANAROMICIMG_COUNT > 0 THEN         BEGIN                     DELETE FROM TBL_VSAT_IMAGE_DETAIL WHERE IMG_TYPE = 'Panaromic' AND IMG_ID = TBL_INSERT;           END;                 END IF; which is doing the same.

for some reason, its not inserting the data. I m sending you the procedure in a fiddle to check if there is any thing wrong
